# Error with android DBAdapter class

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sqlite

here is the error from the logcat of my program.

06-24 01:35:04.213: INFO/ActivityManager(587): 
Starting activity: Intent { comp={one.two/one.two.Arrival} }
06-24 01:35:04.521: ERROR/DBDroid(1048): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: port: , while compiling: SELECT KEY_STATUS, KEY_ID, KEY_ARRIVAL, KEY_DESTINATION, KEY_FERRY FROM ferry
06-24 01:35:05.026: INFO/ActivityManager(587): Displayed activity one.two/.Arrival: 805 ms

It seems that it is stated that there is no table called port.
But i do have a table called port placed into the emulator , under data/data/one.two/databases

And here is my partial code of DBAdapter:

```
    public class DBAdapter extends ListActivity {
public static  String KEY_STATUS = "status";
public static  String KEY_ID = "id";
public static  String KEY_ARRIVAL = "arrival";
public static  String KEY_DESTINATION = "destination";
public static  String KEY_FERRY = "ferry";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ferry";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "port";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

 private static  Context context;
 private static DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
 private static SQLiteDatabase db;
```

By the way does anyone here knows what does this method do :

```
public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, "ferry", null, 1);
    }

@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
    }
}//end DatabaseHelper

// ---opens the database---
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// ---closes the database---
public void close()
{
    DBHelper.close();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Use your constants DATABASE_NAME and DATABASE_VERSION when calling super() in DatabaseHelper constructor.

Comment: Sorry i don't really understand, do you mean by something like this?
super(context, "port" , null, 1) 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You've defined some constants in the class - use it.  super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put table creation code in `DatabaseHelper.onCreate()` method - SQL CREATE statements for all tables you're going to use in other queries.

**edit:**

Unless you're providing ".db" file already created outside Android (e.g. using `SQLite Database Browser` tool - http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net) within your application package (e.g. already populated with data). Then you don't have to put any code here (**moreover** if you put code that will try to create table that exists you'll get an SQL exception).

Comment: I don't have a table creation code, i created a db and edited the data using sqlbrowser and changed the table data there, would this make my code not work?

Comment: So i would leave onCreate method blank?

Comment: Yeah, this ( empty onCreate() ) is not a problem in your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure the table exists ?

Try to open database invoking following commands from shell (I guess `DATABASE_NAME` is the name of database file):

```
adb shell
sqlite3 /data/data/one.two/databases/ferry
```

SQLite console should open. And then list tables:

```
.tables
```

*Use `.quit` to exit SQLite.*

**edit:**

If your database file is ferry.db then `DATABASE_NAME` should also be "ferry.db"

Comment: Hi Gawcio, i followed your instructions and changed the database name to ferry.db , there was a port table in the adb shell.

Comment: I'd like you to post onCreate() method of DatabaseHelper class and query that causes exception.

You can always try to delete database file allowing SQLiteHelper to create it again.